# How can set a row as column in unix

Tags: shell, text-processing

How can I set a row as column in Unix.
Example:

```
name : Keshav
sub  : C++
branch: cse
DOB  :22/09/1990
company:NONE

name : Vijay
sub  : Java
branch: cse
DOB  :22/09/1985
company:NONE
```

I want output like this:

```
name     sub   branch  DOB           company
Keshav   C++   cse     22/09/1990    NONE
Vijay    Java  cse     22/09/1990    NONE
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a shell script to do this, but `perl` would be suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":|\n";RS=""}NR==1{print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9}{print $2,$4,$6,$8,$10}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put the header manually and run the following `awk` on the file:

```
awk -F: '{count++; printf("%s ",$2); if (count>5){count=0; printf("\n");}}' x.txt >> res.txt
```

Assuming `x.txt` contains the inputs as you have and `res.txt` is a prepared file with headers as follows:

```
name sub branch DOB company
```

The resulting output will be:

```
name  sub  branch  DOB  company
 Keshav  C++  cse 22/09/1990 NONE
 Vijay  Java  cse 22/09/1985 NONE
```